# Typescript: chains of abstract classes with overrides

Tags: typescript, oop, overriding, abstract-class, abstract

I have a root abstract object:

```
export abstract class GameBase {
  // takes a string and executes the given move
  public abstract move(move: string): GameBase;

  // a bunch of other helpful stuff, some abstract, some not
}
```

I want to create another *abstract* class that's only used in certain types of games that slightly modifies the interface:

```
export abstract class GameBaseSimultaneous extends GameBase {
  // Same as above, but these games need a boolean flag 
  abstract override move(move: string, partial: boolean): GameBaseSimultaneous;

  // everything else in the parent class is great and I want to keep
}
```

But with or without the `override` keyword, I keep getting a TS2416 error about how the types are not assignable, and of course they're not. I thought that's what `override` was for. Clearly I'm misunderstanding something fundamental. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? How do inherit from an abstract class into another abstract class and modify only certain parts of the interface?

Thank you!

Comment: is https://tsplay.dev/wj8GMm fine?

Comment: This looks more like types/interfaces rather then abstract classes. Do they non-abstract methods?

Comment: There are other defined methods that I want to inherit. I did finally find a similar question with the answer (that I don't love) of "you can't." There are other approaches. I guess I'll have to go with one of those. Thanks!